# How do I get under shingles to replace the roof edge flashing?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, flashing

I am rebuilding an eave on my house and have gotten to the part where I need to figure out how to install the flashing. The eave goes around a corner and the flashing covers a 4" space between the eave and the roof. Also, the flashing runs along the main part of the edge and extends about a 1". The existing flashing is sheet lead and dates to 1910. Unfortunately it has deteriorated and needs to be replaced.

The problem is that the old flashing is nailed to the roof under the shingles. How do I get under them to remove the old flashing and attach the new flashing?

Comment: Hmmm...you say, "the space between the eave and roof." I don't understand. To me, the eave is PART of the ROOF.

Comment: @LeeSam At the corner the eave comes away from the roof.

Comment: If the eve end flashing needs replacing the shingles or other roofing most likely needs replacing as well.

Comment: I agree with @LeeSam. It's not clear what you're describing. The eave is the bottom edge and/or the overhanging portion of the roof. Please check your terminology and provide a photo if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out how to do this on my own. I am posting the answer in case anybody else has the same problem.

The secret to doing this kind of repair or rebuild, as any kind of shingle-related repair, is that you pull up the layer of shingles *above* the one you are working on. So, in my case, I need to pull out the nails from the last row of shingles (or whatever row is over the flashing) using a nail puller. This will allow me to lift up the shingles and expose the nails holding the old flashing. I then will pull up those nails and remove the old flashing. Next, I lift up the shingles, and attach the new flashing by nailing, screwing (or whatever). Finally, I will nail the upper layer of shingles back in again.