# Repair roof flashing that is tucked under gutter rather than over it

Tags: roof, roofing, gutters, flashing

I noticed water dripping from behind the gutter.  When I climbed up to investigate, I found that a piece of flashing was installed incorrectly.   The gutter should be tucked under the flashing.  But instead, the flashing goes behind the gutter and allows water to run off the roof and behind the gutter rather than into the gutter.

The roof was replaced a couple years ago and I'm sure this was installed incorrectly then.   You can see the rusty stains on the gutter from where the old galvanized flashing was in front.  The new aluminum flashing appears to have been installed behind.

This is the only piece of flashing on the house that I've found with this problem so far.  In other places, the flashing appears to be installed correctly over the gutter so that water drains into the gutter.

This is a very short section of roof over my front door.  The edge of the roof, the flashing, and the gutter are only about 10 feet long.

How should I fix this?

What repair steps would be needed for the best solution?

It seems like the options would be:

1. Remove the gutter and put it back on behind the flashing.
2. Un-nail the bottom row of shingles, remove the flashing, then put it back on (like detailed [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/124361/how-do-i-get-under-shingles-to-replace-the-roof-edge-flashing).)
3. Get a pry bar or screwdriver behind the flashing and bend it in front of the gutter without removing anything.

[image: Flashing tucked behind the rain gutter]

Comment: You have three good options there. Which one is best depends on the minutiae of the situation, and it's up to you as the craftsman to choose. What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't want to un-nail the bottom row of shingles because the second row could easily be damaged and now you'd have a roof leak. Bending the flashing might work but if you bend it too much, you'll never straighten it back right. Removing the gutter, or removing enough fasteners to slip the gutter under the flashing would be the best, do it right, option.... and wait until it warms up a bit.